# Optimize generator for multivariate polynomial exponents

Tags: python, optimization, generator, python-itertools

HI, 
I'm try to find a general expression to obtain exponents of a multivariate polynomial of order `order` and with `n_variables`, like the one presented in this [reference](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue1/S01002.pdf) in equation (3).

Here is my current code, which uses an `itertools.product` generator.

```
def generalized_taylor_expansion_exponents( order, n_variables ):
    """
    Find the exponents of a multivariate polynomial expression of order
    `order` and `n_variable` number of variables. 
    """
    exps = (p for p in itertools.product(range(order+1), repeat=n_variables) if sum(p) <= order)
    # discard the first element, which is all zeros..
    exps.next()
    return exps
```

The desired out is this:

```
for i in generalized_taylor_expansion_exponents(order=3, n_variables=3): 
    print i

(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 3, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 0)
```

Actually this code executes fast, because the generator object is only created. If i want to fill a list with values from this generator execution really starts to be slow, mainly because of the high number of calls to `sum`. Tipical value for `order` and `n_variables` is 5 and 10, respectively.

How can i significantly improve execution speed?

Thanks for any help.

Davide Lasagna

Comment: I don't really understand the details of what you're trying to do, but have you looked in numpy to see if there are any functions that can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your biggest performance issue is that most of the tuples you're generating are too big and need to be thrown away.  The following should generate exactly the tuples you want.

```
def generalized_taylor_expansion_exponents( order, n_variables ):
    """
    Find the exponents of a multivariate polynomial expression of order
    `order` and `n_variable` number of variables. 
    """
    pattern = [0] * n_variables
    for current_sum in range(1, order+1):
        pattern[0] = current_sum
        yield tuple(pattern)
        while pattern[-1] < current_sum:
            for i in range(2, n_variables + 1):
                if 0 < pattern[n_variables - i]:
                    pattern[n_variables - i] -= 1
                    if 2 < i:
                        pattern[n_variables - i + 1] = 1 + pattern[-1]
                        pattern[-1] = 0
                    else:
                        pattern[-1] += 1
                    break
            yield tuple(pattern)
        pattern[-1] = 0
```

Comment: Yes, the problem you mentioned is True. Actually this solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try writing it recursively so as to generate only the desired elements:

```
def _gtee_helper(order, n_variables):
    if n_variables == 0:
        yield ()
        return
    for i in range(order + 1):
        for result in _gtee_helper(order - i, n_variables - 1):
            yield (i,) + result


def generalized_taylor_expansion_exponents(order, n_variables):
    """
    Find the exponents of a multivariate polynomial expression of order
    `order` and `n_variable` number of variables. 
    """
    result = _gtee_helper(order, n_variables)
    result.next() # discard the first element, which is all zeros
    return result
```

Comment: I thought of that solution, but there is a lot of overhead to constructing tuples over and over again coming through the recursive layers.  My solution avoided that, at the cost of making the code more complex and opaque.